# Java triangle of n height using recursion

Tags: java

> Assume  the availability of a method  named  makeLine that can be passed a non-negative integer  n and a character  c and return a String  consisting of n identical characters  that are all equal  to c. Write a method  named  printTriangle that receives two integer  parameters  n and k. If n is negative the method  does nothing. If n happens to be an even number, its value  is raised to the next odd number (e.g. 4-->5). Then, when k has the value  zero, the method  prints a SYMMETRIC triangle of O's (the capital letter O) as follows: first a line of n O, followed by a line of n-2 O's (indented by one space), and then a line of n-4 O's (indented by two spaces), and so on. For example, if the method  received 5,0 (or 4,0) it would print:

```
OOOOO
 OOO
  O
```

Note: in the above output , the first line contains 0 spaces before the first O, the next line 1 space, and so on.

Note: These instructions state what the method  does when k is zero, but it is up to you, the programmer, to determine what it does when k is not zero and use it for your advantage.

The method  must not use a loop of any kind (for, while, do-while) to accomplish its job. The method  should invoke makeLine to accomplish the task of creating Strings  of varying lengths.

This is what I have so far. I'm having trouble figuring out where to put the spacing. I believe it has something to do with k, but I'm not quite sure.

```
public void printTriangle(int n, int k){ 
    if(n < 0)
        return;
    if(n % 2 == 0) 
        n++;
    if(k == 0){
        System.out.println(makeLine(n, 'O'));
        printTriangle(n-2, 0); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the answer, but hopefully this gives you some hints.  A recursive method is something that solves a problem by calling itself to solve a smaller version of the *same* problem.  In your case, the problem is to print this (I've put `b` where blanks belong):

```
OOOOO
bOOO
bbO
```

You're printing the first line, then solving a smaller version of the same problem, which is to print a smaller triangle:

```
bOOO
bbO
```

The problem is that this smaller version isn't quite the same; it has to have extra spaces before each line.  How much extra space?  Well, that's why the instructor said "use `k` to your advantage".  How could you call the method recursively, and use `k` to tell it to display extra spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem of solving people's "homework". I'll explain how this works to help you learn.

Here is how the code works.

First, like you did, you must check if the value n is odd. If it is, increment the value like you have, to make it even.

Now you need to build your 'triangle'. Do this by using recursion. For each row of the triangle, you need to print the spaces, then the 'O's, then end the line by printing the spaces.

In your example the 'X's represent spaces, and the 'O' represent the triangle:

```
OOOOO
XOOOX
XXOXX
```

Furthermore, look at a bigger example:

```
OOOOOOOOO
XOOOOOOOX
XXOOOOOXX
XXXOOOXXX
XXXXOXXXX
```

As you can see, each time a new line is added, one extra space is added on each side. Therefore, you can use 'k' to your advantage to print the spaces. Added 1 to 'k' for each recursive execution, will take care of this. Now you simply have to edit your `System.out.println()` statement to add the `makeLine` so that you draw the spaces (or 'X's), as well as the 'O's.

```
public void printTriangle(int n, int k){ 
    if(n <= 0)
        return;
    if(n % 2 == 0) 
        n++;
    System.out.println(makeLine(k, ' ') + makeLine(n, 'O') + makeLine(k, ' '));
    printTriangle(n-2, k+1); 
}
```

Hope this helps! Please feel free to ask questions if you have them.

Comment: Sorry @Makoto, I get hasty in my answers and forget that sometimes people need to understand why the code works, just as much, or even more, than having the code working.