# Java Printing a triangle using recursion

Tags: java

Assume  the availability of a method  named  `makeLine` that can be passed a non-negative integer  `n` and a character  `c` and return a string  consisting of n identical characters  that are all equal  to `c`.

Write a method  named  `printTriangle` that receives two integer  parameters  `n` and `k`. If `n` is negative the method  does nothing. If `n` happens to be an even number, its value  is raised to the next odd number (e.g. 4-->5). Then, when `k` has the value  zero, the method  prints a symmetric triangle of `O`'s (the capital letter `O`) as follows: first a line of `n` `O`, followed by a line of `n-2` `O`'s (indented by one space), and then a line of `n-4` `O`'s (indented by two spaces), and so on. For example, if the method  received 5,0 (or 4,0) it would print:

```
OOOOO
 OOO
  O
```

Note: In the above output, the first line contains 0 spaces before the first `O`, the next line 1 space, and so on.

Note: These instructions state what the method  does when `k` is zero, but it is up to you, the programmer, to determine what it does when `k` is not zero and use it for your advantage.

The method  must not use a loop of any kind (`for`, `while`, `do`-`while`) to accomplish its job. The method  should invoke `makeLine` to accomplish the task of creating strings  of varying lengths.

Here is my code:

```
public void printTriangle(int n, int k) {
if (n <= 0)
    return;

if(n%2 == 0)
   n++;

  System.out.println(makeLine(k, ' ')+ makeLine(n, 'O') +makeLine(k, ' '));
  printTriangle(n-2,k++);

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

You should change:

```
printTriangle(n - 2, k++);
```

to:

```
printTriangle(n - 2, ++k);
```

With `k++`, you call `printTriangle` with the old value of `k`. Only after the recursive call is over, the k is incremented. With `++k` you increment `k` before the recursive call.

Comment: Is there anything else wrong with the code? It still doesn't seem to work. It says "The value of _stdout is incorrect."

Comment: WIth the code you provided no.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you

```
private String makeLine(int k, char c) {
    if (k <= 0) {
        return "";
    }
    //in each recursive call a character is added
    return c + makeLine(k - 1, c);
}

public void printTriangle(int n, int k) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    /*
    n*2-1 : 
            n=3 -> 5, 
            n=2 -> 3, 
            n=1 -> 1
    */
    System.out.println(makeLine(k, ' ') + 
            makeLine(n * 2 - 1, '0') + makeLine(k, ' '));
    printTriangle(n - 1, k + 1);
}
```

in other place use

```
printTriangle(3, 0);
```

get

```
00000
 000 
  0
```

**EDIT 1**

without makeLine method

```
public void printTriangle(int n, int k) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    // the value by default in char is '\0'
    System.out.println(new String(new char[k]).replace('\0', ' ')
            + new String(new char[n * 2 - 1]).replace('\0', '0')
            + new String(new char[k]).replace('\0', ' ')
    );
    printTriangle(n - 1, k + 1);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without editing makeLine()?

Comment: @javajavahut of course, in edit 1 ..... i show a code without makeLine

Comment: that disappointment help people who copied code [copy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27182155/4767343) :-(